# Sql Trigger Error explaination?

Tags: sql, triggers, compiler-errors

I have been working on this trigger for a while and seem to be stuck. I feel that my logic is somewhat correct but when I run the code, I get this error message:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Message_Student_ForInsert, Line 9
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Here is my code:

```
Create Trigger Message_Student_ForInsert
ON CourseEnrolled

For Insert

AS
Begin
 Declare @Id int
 Select @Id = StudentID from inserted

 insert into CourseAudit
 Values ('New Student with Id = ' + Cast(@Id as nvarchar(10)) + ' is added at ' + cast(GetDate() as nvarchar(30)))
END
```

I have created a table name CourseAudit as well in an attempt to try and solve this error. I thought the error meant that I am missing values inside of the tables - since I haven't inserted any yet. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your INSERT statement is incorrect. Learn more here; [INSERT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

Based on your code, one assumes the table [CourseAudit] exists and has a nvarchar() column in it.

You need to specify the column name for the insert.

If you omit the column name, then you should suply a value for ALL columns, in the order on which they appear in the table definition.

Example:

```
insert into CourseAudit (SomeCulumnNameHere)
Values ('New Student with Id = ' + Cast(@Id as nvarchar(10)) 
       + ' is added at ' + cast(GetDate() as nvarchar(30)))
```